# How to determine which rc file my tmux session sources when creating a new window?

Tags: bash, tmux

My tmux is acting "weirdly" and I don't know what is happening.

A while ago, I defined a `prompt_git` function inside my `.bashrc` file, and started using tmux regularly. Later, I removed this function from the `.bashrc` file. After that, whenever I create a new tmux session or create a new window in an existing tmux session, it will keep giving me this error `-bash: prompt_git: command not found` until I manually do `source ~/.bashrc`. I'm pretty sure I've removed every pieces of `prompt_git` from all my bash related files, e.g. `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` etc.

What makes it more puzzling is that new tmux session does automatically source my current `.bashrc` file. I confirmed this by adding `echo "hello, this is from .bashrc file"` line into `.bashrc` file, and I can see this message every time I created a new tmux session. But I still have to `source ~/.bashrc` again to remove the aforementioned error message.

I have been using tmux only for a couple of months, so maybe there're subtleties that I'm not aware of. Could anyone give me some debugging suggestions? Thanks a ton!

**Edit 1**

Suggested by meuh, I added the following lines in my `.bashrc` file.

```
prompt_git() {
  sleep 999
}
```

Then, I create a new tmux window inside my current running tmux session (this new window of course is frozen right away), and in an existing tmux window I ran `ps fax` which gave me:

```
3033275 ?        Ss    17:25 tmux -CC new -s main
 573620 pts/8    Ss     0:00  \_ -bash
 578771 pts/8    R+     0:00  |   \_ ps fax
 578638 pts/7    Ss+    0:00  \_ -bash
 578713 pts/7    S+     0:00      \_ -bash
 578714 pts/7    S+     0:00          \_ sleep 999
```

I'm using the [iTerm2 tmux integration](https://iterm2.com/documentation-tmux-integration.html) hence `-CC` option is used.

If I do `lsof -p 578714` (the last line above), it gives me

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
sleep   578714  hwu  cwd    DIR   0,50      4096 211943425 /home/hwu (10.5.0.81:/home)
sleep   578714  hwu  rtd    DIR   0,20      4096         2 /
sleep   578714  hwu  txt    REG   0,20     33128        50 /usr/bin/sleep
sleep   578714  hwu  mem    REG   0,20 106176928     11148 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
sleep   578714  hwu  mem    REG   0,20   2156272       141 /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
sleep   578714  hwu  mem    REG   0,20    163312       123 /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
sleep   578714  hwu    0u   CHR  136,7       0t0        10 /dev/pts/7
sleep   578714  hwu    1w  FIFO   0,11       0t0  84140428 pipe
sleep   578714  hwu    2u   CHR  136,7       0t0        10 /dev/pts/7
```

Going backwards, `lsof -p 578713` gives

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
bash    578713  hwu  cwd    DIR   0,50      4096 211943425 /home/hwu (10.5.0.81:/home)
bash    578713  hwu  rtd    DIR   0,20      4096         2 /
bash    578713  hwu  txt    REG   0,20    964536        21 /usr/bin/bash
bash    578713  hwu  mem    REG   0,20     61560       189 /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
bash    578713  hwu  mem    REG   0,20 106176928     11148 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
bash    578713  hwu  mem    REG   0,20   2156272       141 /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
bash    578713  hwu  mem    REG   0,20     19248       145 /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
bash    578713  hwu  mem    REG   0,20    174576       217 /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.5.9
bash    578713  hwu  mem    REG   0,20    163312       123 /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
bash    578713  hwu  mem    REG   0,20     26970      1382 /usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
bash    578713  hwu    0u   CHR  136,7       0t0        10 /dev/pts/7
bash    578713  hwu    1w  FIFO   0,11       0t0  84140428 pipe
bash    578713  hwu    2u   CHR  136,7       0t0        10 /dev/pts/7
bash    578713  hwu  255u   CHR  136,7       0t0        10 /dev/pts/7
```

`lsof -p 578638` gives

```
bash    578638  hwu  cwd    DIR   0,50      4096 211943425 /home/hwu (10.5.0.81:/home)
bash    578638  hwu  rtd    DIR   0,20      4096         2 /
bash    578638  hwu  txt    REG   0,20    964536        21 /usr/bin/bash
bash    578638  hwu  mem    REG   0,20     61560       189 /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
bash    578638  hwu  mem    REG   0,20 106176928     11148 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
bash    578638  hwu  mem    REG   0,20   2156272       141 /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
bash    578638  hwu  mem    REG   0,20     19248       145 /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
bash    578638  hwu  mem    REG   0,20    174576       217 /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.5.9
bash    578638  hwu  mem    REG   0,20    163312       123 /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
bash    578638  hwu  mem    REG   0,20     26970      1382 /usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
bash    578638  hwu    0u   CHR  136,7       0t0        10 /dev/pts/7
bash    578638  hwu    1u   CHR  136,7       0t0        10 /dev/pts/7
bash    578638  hwu    2u   CHR  136,7       0t0        10 /dev/pts/7
bash    578638  hwu    3r  FIFO   0,11       0t0  84140428 pipe
bash    578638  hwu  255u   CHR  136,7       0t0        10 /dev/pts/7
```

and `lsof -p 3033275` gives

```
COMMAND     PID USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
tmux    3033275  hwu  cwd       DIR               0,50     4096 211943425 /home/hwu (10.5.0.81:/home)
tmux    3033275  hwu  rtd       DIR               0,20     4096         2 /
tmux    3033275  hwu  txt       REG               0,20   423128      5368 /usr/bin/tmux
tmux    3033275  hwu  mem       REG               0,20    61560       189 /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
tmux    3033275  hwu  mem       REG               0,20   142144       205 /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
tmux    3033275  hwu  mem       REG               0,20    19248       145 /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
tmux    3033275  hwu  mem       REG               0,20  2156272       141 /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
tmux    3033275  hwu  mem       REG               0,20   109976       207 /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
tmux    3033275  hwu  mem       REG               0,20   297792      2434 /usr/lib64/libevent-2.0.so.5.1.9
tmux    3033275  hwu  mem       REG               0,20   174576       217 /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.5.9
tmux    3033275  hwu  mem       REG               0,20   163696      1514 /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.5.9
tmux    3033275  hwu  mem       REG               0,20    14424       221 /usr/lib64/libutil-2.17.so
tmux    3033275  hwu  mem       REG               0,20   163312       123 /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
tmux    3033275  hwu    0u      CHR                1,3      0t0      1028 /dev/null
tmux    3033275  hwu    1u      CHR                1,3      0t0      1028 /dev/null
tmux    3033275  hwu    2u      CHR                1,3      0t0      1028 /dev/null
tmux    3033275  hwu    3u  a_inode               0,12        0      9185 [eventpoll]
tmux    3033275  hwu    4u     unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0  61604412 socket
tmux    3033275  hwu    5u     unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0  61604413 socket
tmux    3033275  hwu    6u     unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0  84134152 /tmp/tmux-614/default
tmux    3033275  hwu    7u     unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0  61604414 /tmp/tmux-614/default
tmux    3033275  hwu    8u     unix 0x0000000000000000      0t0  62276472 /tmp/tmux-614/default
tmux    3033275  hwu    9u      CHR                5,2      0t0      1132 /dev/ptmx
tmux    3033275  hwu   10u      CHR                5,2      0t0      1132 /dev/ptmx
```

**Edit 2**

I don't have a `.tmux.conf` file in my $HOME directory and neither a `.tmux` dir. Tried `find $HOME -type f -print | grep prompt_git` but it still gave me nothing.

Comment: My GUESS is that you didn't completely remove `prompt_git`.  Are you willing to post your .bashrc?

Comment: I did `grep -n 'prompt_git' * .[^.]*` in my `$HOME` directory, and nothing is found. Also, it doesn't give such an error message in a regular shell instead of tmux.

Comment: Since something must be calling `prompt_git` which is no longer there, you could create a shell script of that name in your PATH and put a `sleep 999` in it, then open a new window and look with `ps fax` at what is doing the call. There is only one tmux server for all the sessions. You can kill it (and all sessions!!) with `tmux kill-server`. You can look at the environment vars for a session with `tmux show-environment -g -t sessionname` and this might give a clue; `tmux  set-environment -u varname` can be used to unset a variable.

Comment: @meuh Thanks for this suggestion. I saw in `ps fax` the following lines
`3033275 ?        Ss    17:24 tmux -CC new -s main, 573620 pts/8    Ss     0:00  \_ -bash, 573986 pts/8    R+     0:00  |   \_ ps fax, 573893 pts/10   Ss+    0:00  \_ -bash, 573968 pts/10   S+     0:00      \_ -bash, 573969 pts/10   S+     0:00          \_ sleep 999
` Sorry the comment doesn't support multiline code block... I separate each line by a coma. I use `-CC` command here because I'm using the [iTerm2 tmux integration](https://iterm2.com/documentation-tmux-integration.html).

Comment: You should edit the ps output into your original post to have it formatted. You might be able to see which script each bash is running by doing `lsof -p pid` where pid is the process id.

Comment: @meuh Good call. I've edited the original post and also included `lsof -p pid` outputs.

Comment: The output is disappointing; I was hoping lsof would show the file bash was running as a a script, but it seems it only has a fifo open (eg: 3r  FIFO), so it  is getting commands from outside. Perhaps you have a `~/.tmux.conf` or some other configuration like `conky` which is trying to update the tmux status line or bash prompt or window title. Have a fuller search in some directories eg with `find ~/.tmux/ -type f -print|grep prompt_git`

Comment: I don't have a `.tmux.conf` file in my `$HOME` directory and neither a `.tmux` dir, so instead I did `find . -type f -print | grep prompt_git` and still no luck to find anything.